# Light according to music

Tags: ios, frameworks, ios5, light

I would like to know if there is any framework that supports sound analyze and do some action according to it. On the App Store, there is an app called Musical Light. It animates the lights during the music. Is there any framework that can support this?

---

Ok, here's what I've discovered:
The AVAudioPlayer has two methods: `averagePowerForChannel:` and `peakPowerForChannel:`
These values can be translated to the [0, 1] interval. So you can write a method to light on a light when the values reach a preset value.

Anybody else has any other idea to succeed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CoreAudio, AudioToolbox, AVFoundation - all of them are in iOS SDK.
You can get some info about music track from its sound buffer, but all logic and analysis will be in your code.